# df says I have 20G more disk space used than du. Why?

Tags: disk-usage

I used du to list all folders and sort by size, the results simply doesn't add up to how much disk space is used(using df). There's about 20G in discrepency, why?

```
[root@xxx lib]# du --max-depth=1 -h /| sort -n -r
310M    /lib
123M    /root
96K /dev
88M /etc
75G /
73G /var
30M /sbin
20M /boot
20K /tmp
18M /lib64
16K /mnt
16K /lost+found
12K /home
8.0K    /srv
8.0K    /selinux
8.0K    /opt
8.0K    /misc
8.0K    /media
7.0M    /bin
1.2G    /usr
0   /sys
0   /proc
[root@xxx lib]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      298G   94G  189G  34% /
/dev/sda1              99M   26M   69M  28% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: So... you expect us to sum the values. Please use `du -smc /* | sort -n -r` vs. `df -m` instead (also fixes the broken sort)

Comment: Instead of sorting numerically, you should treat those numbers as human readable numbers: `du --max-depth=1 -h / | sort -hr`. This will put "75G /" first.

Comment: @casey we want to do this the other way around, maybe. see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2721/29146

Comment: Useful info here: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311)

Answer (score 11):

That's because `du` and `df` measure different things.

`man du` says:

> du - estimate **file space usage** (...) Summarize **disk usage of each FILE**, recursively for directories.

and `man df`:

> df - report **file system disk space usage**

File systems have inode tables, journals etc. which are not summarized by `du`. It isn't only Linux-specific, but rather UNIX-specific (or even UNIX-filesystem-specific). Because UNIX processes use files for everything (I'm simplifying) i.e. writing to log files, there could be also an [open file descriptor](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-why-command-df-and-du-reports-different-output.html) problem in this case causing different `du` and `df` outputs.

Comment: Correct.  Also of interest, many filesystems including `ext3` are structured such that directory metadata can grow, but not shrink. So, if you have a high-churn folder (such as a mail spool), the space used by the metadata can grow and grow and grow.  Replacing it with a new directory periodically can dramatically drop disk usage.

Comment: Given `0 /sys` it looks like du also doesn't include directory tables - which is odd, because they do have a user-visible size - `ls -ld [some dir]` will show it (often 4096, one filesystem block, for small directories on ext2)

Comment: @Xaerxess: While this is technically possible, it's unlikely that deleted files or race conditions (another possibility for `du` to miss things) would account for 20GB.

Comment: @jmtd: A high-churn folder would grow to the maximum-ever size and then stop.

Comment: @Random832: No, `du` includes directory tables. The size is 0 for `/proc` and `/sys` simply because these filesystems report a size of 0 for everything.

Comment: @random832 `/sys/` is a virtual filesystem. It doesn't actually exist so it takes up no space.

Comment: @Shadur I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that. Maybe I thought the mount point directory on the root filesystem would be counted somehow.

Comment: @Random832 You probably forgot that it was a mounted file system and not a directory; it's an easy mistake to make, seeing as that's an entirely *nix-flavour-specific thing.

Answer (score 4):

The [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) table (as well as a few very much smaller things) is included in the used space. It looks like you have about 18GB of inodes. That's around 6% of the space, which is in the expected ballpark for ext2/ext3/ext4 (filesystems that don't have an inode table are likely to have larger directory entries if nothing else). You can find the precise size used for inodes by running `tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00`, e.g. here are the relevant lines for one of my 20GB ext3 filesystems:

```
Inode count:              2622368
Inode size:               128
```

That partition has 2622368×128 B ≈ 320 MB of inodes.

Additional note: the way you've invoked `du`, you'll see spaced used by every file even on remote mounts and other non-directly-disked-backed filesystems. Run `du -x /` to see just what's stored on the root filesystem.