# `du -sh` reports different used size than `df -h`

Tags: disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [linux free disk space confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/linux-free-disk-space-confusion)
>   [Why is there a discrepancy in disk usage reported by df and du?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du)

`df -h` says that I have 494G used on `/var`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             564G  494G   41G  93% /var
```

But `du -sh /var` says it's `350G`

What makes them different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`du` looks at files, while `df` looks at the filesystem. If you have a small or empty file, `du` knows the real file size by really looking into it, while `df` will see that the file has some size, depending on the "[block size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28data_storage%29)" that was set when the partition was created. The block size determines the minimum size of files on the filesystem. While there maybe other causes, I think this is the most obvious difference between `df` and `du`.

See also [How do I determine the block size of an ext3 partition on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/29887/19291)

Comment: Wrong.  Both use the number of blocks by default.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the filesystems ufs, reiser, ext2, ext3, and ext4 (there may be others) have a reserve of a given percentage of disk to be use exclusively by the root userid.  This is basically a safety valve allowing the root users or root processes to continue to use disk when things get close on disk while denying the supposedly less important non-root users.

On ext2, and ext3, I believe that the default reservation is 5%, much too high with the sizes of partitions these days.  What I usually do is this to my ext filesystems:

```
 tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda3
```

This is generally safe to change while the disk is mounted.  However, you might have to remount the disk to make it effective immediately.